# removing a css class from group of li elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, meteor

This Meteor client code needs to remove the class `select` from all `li` elements which are children of `ul` which has id `sub-menu`, the class format is `class1 class2 select`
any ideas? thx

```
$('ul#sub-menu > li').each(() => {
        const classProp = $(this).className;
        if (classProp.indexOf('select') >= 0) { //de-selecting
          const lastIndex = classProp.lastIndexOf(" ");
          $(this).className = classProp.substring(0, lastIndex);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method instead of making it complex.

```
$('ul#sub-menu > li').removeClass('select');
```

---

There are several bugs in your code [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is the property of DOM element so remove the jQuery wrapping.

```
this.className
```

---

Although there is build in method to remove class name from DOM element by getting [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property.

```
this.classList.remove("select");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this

```
$('ul#sub-menu li').removeClass('select');
```

**OR**

```
$('ul#sub-menu').find('li').removeClass('select');
```